# Ubuntu-compatible laptops

Tags: dell, laptop, lenovo, thinkpad

I've seen the Ubuntu certified list, and have gone through it systematically. However, even for the laptops that are on there, there seem to be issues, e.g. around sleep/wake. I've spent a lot of time searching through other posts, but many pages make recommendations without really having tried Ubuntu on that machine.

My questions:

(1) Is there a definite, up-to-date list somewhere, where people contribute their own experiences? Ideally, such a list would show what is currently available to buy, with rough prices.

(2) I would either like to buy a low-cost basic laptop (<£500, including refurb machines) or spend a good amount (>£1000+) on something that's really good. I don't want to spend £1000 on something that's just so-so. I should be <14", to be vaguely portable: 11"-14" is ok!

(2a) What could I get as a low-cost basic laptop that runs Ubuntu ok? I would be happy to get one in the interim while I keep looking for a better one. Really, if there's a very cheap suggestion (around £300?) I'd be happy with it.

(2b) what could I get as a high-end laptop? I would love USB-C-charging, good screen with touch (probably FHD rather than UHD for bettery; doesn't need to be convertible, but ideally would lie flat), good battery life, good keyboard, light weight. Performance less important, as it'll be a general-use machine (but at least 8GB ram, ideally 16gb).

I've looked at the ASUS ZenBook 13 UX331UA, Lenovo ThinkPad L390, Lenovo ThinkPad X390, Lenovo ThinkPad X390 Yoga, Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon / Yoga, Yoga 520/730/930. However, when you start reading forums and blog-posts, they all seem to have issues, e.g. around S3 sleep or some basic hardware (like microohone not working).

I've looked at the Dell XPS 13, but there's a new 2-in-1 coming, so Dell is the choice, I would want to wait. (Though I cannot quite believe that Dell is the only option for running Ubuntu - clearly they have a good rep, and the XPS is top of my list, but would want to wait for the 2-in-1.)

(3) If this isn't the right forum for the discussion on Ubuntu-compatible devices, would you be able to recommend where to discuss it?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: We do not offer hardware support. But my HP Omen 17" works very well with linux. Thing is... there is no such place (that is totally up to date). Best I can offer: make a live USB installer, take it with you to your local vendor and try it out on their machines. For online sales ... google the specs. In case you are in Germany, or Europe: https://www.tuxedocomputers.com/en# ;-) There are more like that across the world

Answer (score 2):

1. No.
2. Yours to decide. I am not telling, advising or ordering you what to get. Totally yours to decide upon. I took 3 months to decide on my new machine checking pages online  ;)

> If this isn't the right forum for the discussion on Ubuntu-compatible devices, would you be able to recommend where to discuss it?

Your Ubuntu Local Community team will know: http://loco.ubuntu.com/